# call a function (actually an API call) whenever user place order

Tags: woocommerce

I need to call a function (actually an API call) whenever user place order(i.e after checkout).

I searched woo-commerce doc (https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)  but could not find proper hook.
Already i have wasted lot of time for this and client need this to be done.
If anyone can suggest anything then it will very helpful. I am new to woo-commerce.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which API call do you want to make?

Comment: That i am going to build. Client is already running business and all admin process is handled by other application. They are adding e-commerce feature and they want to get order details to other application. I just want to know how to trigger a action when order is placed. @Karthik

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your theme's function.php or in your custom plugin Place this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'my_function');
function my_function(){
    // Whatever I want to do when payment is completed
    // Like api call to external server etc
}
```

This action triggers when payment is completed. There are other actions available instead of `woocommerce_payment_complete` like `woocommerce_order_status_pending` , `woocommerce_thankyou` etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: woocommerce_checkout_order_processed worked better for me. Thanks for help. Due to woocommerce_payment_complete i am able to find this.

Comment: Since we're talking about functionality the code should be in a plugin and not in theme's functions.php.

Comment: How can we get the id of the order inside the function?

Comment: @Sytham very old comment, but just in case someone stumbles onto this comment: `my_function( $order_id )` - the callback to the action automatically passes the $order_id as an argument, so you can use it within the function.